# Tizen wearable web app with localization

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I am trying to get localization enabled in a tizen web application for wearables. 
I am following https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/localization to get localization.

I have language.js set up for languages inside locales and a default one. 
The contents are generated by tizen studio and look like

```js
TIZEN_L10N=
{
 "todays_food_intake" : "Today's food intake",
 "todays_water_intake" : "Today's water intake"
};
```

In my index.html, I have put `<script src="language.js"></script>` inside the `<head>`.

and trying to use it in divs as `<h4 class="some-class">TIZEN_L10N['todays_food_intake']</h4>`

But it does not seem to be working.

In the wearable app I am getting TIZEN_L10N['todays_food_intake'] and not the localized string.

What may I be missing.

PS: I am an Android dev.

Comment: Did you see the sample app of localization ?

Comment: @Iqbalhossain Can't find sample app of localization? Where to find such sample. I am always finding dead end with their documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your translations in `languages.js` files in `/locales/de-de`, `/locales/en-us` etc. Example `language.js`:

```
TIZEN_L10N = {
    'lorem': 'ipsum',
    'foo': 'bar'
}
```

Then add an attribute to the elements in your HTML that should have a localized string:

```
<span data-l10n="lorem"></span>
```

In your JS, add this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('[data-l10n]').length; i++) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[data-l10n]')[i];
    elem.innerHTML = TIZEN_L10N[elem.getAttribute('data-l10n')];
}
```

This will loop through all elements with the `data-l10n` attribute and set its `innerHTML` to the translated string for the key found in its `data-l10n` attribute.